# Workflow status column gets cleared after completion of approval process

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, blog, approval-process

I am using **SharePoint Online**, where I have created a blog subsite, in the Blog SubSite Posts List i have configured Approval Workflow. Once the list item is approved, Approval status becomes **approved** (that is  working fine)

But after sometime the approval status column become empty for that item. 
I am not sure why it is happening as I have configured approval workflow so many places but didn't see this kind of issue. Kindly suggest the solution.

Comment: Workflow is related to tasks..kindly check if someone is deleting task items from task list..

Comment: I have checked already, actually one more time i have got this issue but thought might be some another cause i am getting this but again i got the same.

Answer (score 0):

This may help .If you have more look up columns in your list then this kind of issues will come.

https://vladandreipopescu.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/first-blogas/

Comment: In Posts List there is only one LookUp Column is available by default '# Comments', except that i did not added any lookup column. actually this is not happening usually,sometime only i got this issue. In the same list there are almost 100 items and only for 1 or 2 items this is happening.